# ¿Cómo puedo contar las veces que se repiten números en un archivo(Python)?

Tags: python

Mi programa cuenta los datos de un archivo de texto, este es el archivo de texto:

```
-100
200
100
200
300
300
100
200
```

Este es mi código:

```
def read_data(filename):
    numbers = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line != "\n" and line[0] != ' ':
                numbers.append(float(line))
    return numbers

def rep_data(numbers):
    contar = {}
    for n in numbers:
        if n in contar:
            contar[n] += 1
        else:
            contar[n] = 0
    for k,m in contar.items():
        print (k,': ', m)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_data('mydata2.txt')
    rep = rep_data(data)
    print ("Data: {0}".format(data))
```

La consola me da el resultado y el programa corre pero no cuenta las repeticiones

```
-100.0 :  0
200.0 :  2
100.0 :  1
300.0 :  1
Data: [-100.0, 200.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 300.0, 100.0, 200.0]
```

¿Cuál es el error en mi código?

Comment: Donde dice `contar[n] = 0` debe decir `contar[n] = 1`, pues ya tienes el primer ejemplar del numero n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
with open("mydata2.txt", "r") as archivo:
    texto = sorted(archivo.read().split())
    for valor in set(texto):
        print(valor, texto.count(valor))
```

produce:

```
-100 1
200 3
300 2
100 2    

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Con `archivo.read()` leo todo el archivo como un solo bloque de texto, que divido en valores usando `split()`, lo que me da una lista de valores en formato string:

```
texto -> ['-100', '100', '100', '200', '200', '200', '300', '300']
```

Con `set(texto)` obtengo un *conjunto* con los valores sin repetición:

```
{'-100', '200', '300', '100'}
```

Con el `for` recorro estos valores únicos, usando la función `count()` para obtener el número de apariciones en la lista original.

**Como diccionario**

Si quieres obtener un diccionario con las cuentas, puedes usar una comprensión de diccionarios:

```
with open("mydata2.txt", "r") as archivo:
    texto = archivo.read().split()
    data = {valor: texto.count(valor) for valor in set(texto)}
    print(data)
```

produce:

```
{'-100': 1, '300': 2, '200': 3, '100': 2}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

A tu función `rep_data` le hace falta un `return` para que pueda devolverte el diccionario con el conteo de datos y en el `print ("Data: {0}".format(data))` estas imprimiendo `data` que es la lista de números, pero si deseas implimir el conteo de datos tendrías que imprimir `rep`

Por cierto, tu conteo de datos devuelve el total de cada número - 1. También lo puedes simplificar si utilizas el método `get()` del diccionario contar

Ejemplo completo:

```
def read_data(filename):
    numbers = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line != "\n" and line[0] != ' ':
                numbers.append(float(line))
    return numbers

def rep_data(numbers):
    contar = {}
    for n in numbers:
        contar[n] = contar.get(n, 0) + 1
    for k,m in contar.items():
        print (k,': ', m)
    return contar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_data('mydata2.txt')
    rep = rep_data(data)
    print ("Data: {0}".format(rep))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
-100.0 :  1
200.0 :  3
100.0 :  2
300.0 :  2
Data: {-100.0: 1, 200.0: 3, 100.0: 2, 300.0: 2}
```